# php regex select less code

Tags: php, regex, less

I want to select all less code from a file .But i can not find the right way to do it.

This is my code so far

```
$d = <<<EOT
.class {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image: url(images/fallback-gradient.png);
}
.id {
    b:100%;
    bc: url(images/fallback-gradient.png);
}

& when ( @main_container_top_option = true) {
  .fast_menu_option {
    .gpicon {
      color: transparent;
    } 
  } 
}
EOT;

$pattern = '/.*\{(?s:.*?)\}$/mi';

$t = preg_match_all($pattern, $d, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
foreach ($out[0] as $key) {
    echo '<br><pre>'.$key."</pre>";
}
```

And this is the result:

```
.class {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image: url(images/fallback-gradient.png);
}

.id {
    b:100%;
    bc: url(images/fallback-gradient.png);
}

& when ( @main_container_top_option = true) {
  .fast_menu_option {
    .gpicon {
      color: transparent;
    }
```

For the first 2 classes is ok but last one is not ok because they are missing 2 other }.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Then it means you don't want to match pure CSS?

Comment: no pure css but less

Comment: Isn't `.class` attributes pure CSS?

Comment: yes but it works the same in less

Comment: You should clear what you are going to match and what you are not in a more precise manner.

Comment: I don't think it's ever possible to use regex here (unless we're taking about very-very tiny subsets of CSS or Less). I.e. even if you fix your nested brackets, imagine what would happen if the code contains comments and strings having `;}{` inside etc. (There're a lot more context-dependent grammar in Less). Impossible w/o less or more descent parser.

Comment: I fixed it, anyway thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to match individual blocks, so a recursive pattern will return balanced braces.  As stated in comments under the question, this method may break when character anomalies occur.  I believe there are css parsers out "in the wild" but I don't have any to recommend.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6JBWD))

```
if (preg_match_all('~.*\{((?R)|[^}])*}~', $d, $out)) {
    echo implode("\n---\n",$out[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
.class {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image: url(images/fallback-gradient.png);
}
---
.id {
    b:100%;
    bc: url(images/fallback-gradient.png);
}
---
& when ( @main_container_top_option = true) {
  .fast_menu_option {
    .gpicon {
      color: transparent;
    } 
  } 
}
```

If you don't need to separate the blocks, you can modify the pattern like this:

```
~[^{]*\{((?R)|[^}])*}~
```

But then it depends on what your *actual* input.